# Swift: ReadMoreTextView Library Tap Detection

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello I'm currently using the open-source ReadMoreTextView library to expand my description. How do I go about detecting only when "Read More" or "...Read Less" is tapped. Currently when using these functions, hitTest and points, all of the textView is detected. My goal is that when I select "Read More" my textView and my tableView header will expand or collapse when its "Read Less". These are the two functions that could help but idk what's the right approach. Much thanks!

```
let descriptionTextView: ReadMoreTextView = {
    let textView = ReadMoreTextView()
    let readMoreTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    ]
    let readLessTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    ]
    textView.attributedReadMoreText = NSAttributedString(string: "... Read more", attributes: readMoreTextAttributes)
    textView.attributedReadLessText = NSAttributedString(string: " Read less", attributes: readLessTextAttributes)
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear
    textView.textColor = .white
    textView.shouldTrim = true
    textView.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
    return textView
}()


override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

}

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. After struggling with the ReadMoreTextView Library , i used different library [ExpandableLabel](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel) Library which solved the problem of getting a call back on more button click. Hopes this will resolve your issue too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Anuj! I'll definitely be trying it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can a button to that attribute text Readmore/ReadLess. When you press the button, it will callback to your view controller. Then you need a function to calculate the height of that row of table view. And update it with your state (readmore/readless)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Tap Detection in ReadMoreTextView but I think you can monitoring when your ReadMoreTextView change the size by this method:

```
readMoreTextView.onSizeChange = { }
```